How can I make multiline cursor "levitate" in VS Code?
VS Code column selection puts cursor to the end of line if there is no characters

and e.g. I'd like to remove one indentation level, which results in lines collapsing to themselves

I'd like multiline cursor to act more like in Visual Studio, where it ignores missing characters by  "levitating", adding missing spacing if needed


I don't think it is possible.  I don't see any setting nor extensions that do this.

"e.g. I'd like to remove one indentation level, which results in lines collapsing to themselves" is this the only use case? because that's an XY problem. to do that, you can select the lines and press shift+tab

Press Ctrl+Alt+(Down Arrow or Up Arrow)

This is column selection I'm already aware of, the question is about making it add missing spacing if needed
